# How to access dir() Python attributes on a module object?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python. I am working at a company that uses Python 2.7.

I import a module object that has functions fields and SQLAlchemy classes. I need to do something with the classes. I thought I could get access to the classes by calling `dir()` on the imported module object, and then looping over the values returned from `dir()`, and then testing each value to see if it is a class. I thought this would work:

```
def get_legacy_data_and_serialize(): 
    for m in dir(all_models):
        if inspect.isclass(getattr(all_models, m)):
            print(all_models.m)
```

but I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'm'
```

When I call dirs() I get back items like this:

```
Base
Client
ClientDetail
Comment
Common
Contact
File
FormData
Ghost
Identified
LabSet
Message
Sender
Subscription
Todo
TodoList
User
UserDetail
__all__
__builtins__
__doc__
__file__
__name__
__package__
__path__
_create_practice
add
add_templates
add_todo
and_
app
```

The upper-case names are the names I'm after. How do I access them?

Comment: Try `print(getattr(all_models, m))` instead of `print(all_models.m)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
all_models.m
```

To this:

```
getattr(all_models, m)
```